# Mandatory passcode change

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration-profiles, password

1. I never asked to change it
2. I do not need to change it
3. If I change it, I need to get authorization from my employer since it is a work issued phone.
4. I am unable to use the phone while due authorizations are processed and Apple is responsible for my being beyond reach.
5. I am perfectly able to take care of myself and perfectly cognizant of any consequences.
6. I do not need a machine to force me to take any action that I do not decide to take.
7. This feature should be optional, not mandatory.
8. Get your act together, apple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a rant.

Comment: The rant could be removed with a simple edit. I'm choosing to leave it in and just answer the question. Many people will search and find the solution since the OP here isn't aware they have an easy out and Apple designed this for the user to control.

Answer (score 1):

Open the settings app, find the profiles section, delete the profile that sets your passcode policy.

You have a choice while the device is in your hands. Blame yourself or IT since Apple had your back in this instance.

Comment: +1 for reading between the lines. It wasn't at all clear to me from the rant that this was some corporate profile, rather than default [hitherto unknown to me] Apple behaviour.

Comment: @Tetsujin No worries - we're at the point where no one can know all the valleys and hills and tunnels and bridges and roads and paths in iOS. Over time the things that you can control and tweak from the MDM perspective is enormous. For instance, I can set up profiles and settings to skip most if not all the welcome steps, bind the device to a corporate MDM server out of the box, break all sorts of things that consumers expect to have control of. The question was vague and more than the usual dose of anger. I chose to help others as well as the OP with a positive solution.